# why my model does not train over all the data (Tensorflow 2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, text-classification

I have a code here using the tensorflow.keras.datasets.imdb data, after splitting my data for train and validation (line 45-50) so my training data and training labels are ndarray of (15000,).
while training my model I can see that the model is not iterating through the entire dataset and I'm getting an accuracy of 49.8%

I followed this video : [TensorFlow 2.0 Tutorial - Training the Model - Text Classification P3](https://www.techwithtim.net/tutorials/python-neural-networks/text-classification-p3/) and typed the same program.
this is what I see when I train the model:
[image]

the code:

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

# Loading data
data = keras.datasets.imdb
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = data.load_data(num_words=10000)
# only take 10,000 words that are most frequent
# we get integer encoded words

# Preprocessing
word_index = data.get_word_index()

word_index = {k: (v + 3) for k, v in word_index.items()}
# dict where the keys are words in char form and values are numbers in int form
word_index["<PAD>"] = 0
word_index["<START>"] = 1
word_index["<UNK>"] = 2
word_index["<UNUSED>"] = 3

reverse_word_index = dict([(value, key) for (key, value) in word_index.items()])
# now we have a dict with keys as integers and values as words

train_data = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(train_data, value=word_index["<PAD>"], 
padding="post",
                                                    maxlen=250)
test_data = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(train_data, value=word_index["<PAD>"], 
padding="post",
                                                   maxlen=250)


def decode(text):
    return " ".join([reverse_word_index.get(i, "?") for i in text])


# Model
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(10000, 16))
model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

# Validation data
x_val = train_labels[:10000]
x_train = train_labels[10000:]

y_val = train_labels[:10000]
y_train = train_labels[10000:]

fitModel = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=40, batch_size=512, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), 
verbose=1)
# batch_size is how many reviews are we going to give at once to the model
```

**(note: I don't have an Nvidia GPU, my GPU is RADEON RX)**

Comment: 30 batches of size 512 is a bit more than 15000. Seems like you are using all your data.

Answer (score 1):

I think your model has been trained on 15,000 examples because the number of iterations for each epoch is `15000` /`batch_size` ~ 30. According to the logs, it shows 30/30 for each epoch and the training process also completed 40 epochs. The reason you got low accuracy is probably because of the rate between `train` and `dev` set which is currently 15000:10000 = 60:40. Therefore, it would be better if you split it to the ratio of 80:20 or 90:10 so that the model can see more examples.

Answer (score 0):

with a batch size of 512 your data shows you are training for 30 batches so you are training on   15,360 samples.  Your data shows the model is training well. At the end of 30 epochs you have 100% for training accuracy and 100 % for validation accuracy. I assume you ran model.evaluate on your test set which gave you an accuracy of 49.8%. Since your model is very accurate there is something wrong with your test data. Run model.evaluate on the validation data and you should see 100% accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Every epoch is an iteration over batches of the training set you have specified. In your case, batch size = 512 therefore the model was trained over 512(batch size) * 30(batches) per epoch, which is about 15000ish data points, so your entire set in this case.

You model however is entirely wrong regardless of the above.

Here:

```
x_val = train_labels[:10000]
x_train = train_labels[10000:]

y_val = train_labels[:10000]
y_train = train_labels[10000:]
```

You're specifying for both x and y the same object (labels), therefore your model is learning nothing, at least not features!

The `.fit()` function gives you the option to skip this manual validation split above entirely and do:

```
fitModel = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=40, batch_size=512, validation_split=0.2, verbose=1)
```

`validation_split` inside `fit()` will handle the validation during training and use 20% of data points in this case as specified, which is a good starting point.

You can then do `fitModel.evaluate(x_test, y_test)`